# Get ListViewItem text by index WP RT

Tags: c#, listview, windows-phone-8.1, runtime

How do I get a `ListViewItem` text by this item index? I tried this

```
 txt = historico.Items[i].ToString();
```

but I got this

```
"Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ListViewItem"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the MainPage.xaml:

```
<Page
x:Class="PushNotification_Sampl.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:PushNotification_Sampl"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

<Grid>
    <ListView Name="list">
        <ListViewItem>1</ListViewItem>
        <ListViewItem>2</ListViewItem>
        <ListViewItem>3</ListViewItem>
        <ListViewItem>4</ListViewItem>
        <Button x:Name="getBtn" Click="getBtn_Click">Get</Button>
        <TextBlock x:Name="text" Width="137" Text="check"></TextBlock>
    </ListView>



</Grid>
```

And in MainPage.xaml.cs, I have added the click event for the button:

```
private void getBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        string result = (list.Items[2] as ListViewItem).Content.ToString();
        text.Text = result;

    }
```

This works well in Windows Phone 8.1 app. Successfully tested. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
txt = (historico.Items[i] as ListViewItem).Content.ToString();
```

or

```
txt = (historico.Items[i] as ListViewItem).Text;
```

Comment: `txt = (historico.Items[i] as ListViewItem).Content.ToString();` worked, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
txt = historico.Items[i].Text;
```

Comment: I can't use `Text` after ...`Items[i]` just can use `Equals`, `ToString`, `GetType` and `GetHashCode`

Comment: are all the items in historico of type ListViewItem?

Comment: yes, i create a new ListViewItem every time i add a value in ListView

Comment: and is historico of type ListView?